# How to customize countdown timer in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on Jquery and i am displaying "countdown timer" using jquery and right now i am showing timer of "1 minute 25 seconds" but after this time i am getting "-1 minutes : 59 seconds", There should be display "0 minutes 0 seconds",how can i do this? Here is my current code

```
<script>
var timer2 = "0:25";
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  var timer = timer2.split(':');
  //by parsing integer, I avoid all extra string processing
  var minutes = parseInt(timer[0], 10);
  var seconds = parseInt(timer[1], 10);
  --seconds;
  minutes = (seconds < 0) ? --minutes : minutes;
  if (minutes < 0) clearInterval(interval);
  seconds = (seconds < 0) ? 59 : seconds;
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
  //minutes = (minutes < 10) ?  minutes : minutes;
  $('.countdown').html(minutes + ' minutes : ' + seconds + ' seconds');
  timer2 = minutes + ':' + seconds;
}, 1000);


</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: You have to stop the interval on `minutes === 0` not on `minutes < 0`

Comment: There's `String.prototype.padStart()`: `seconds.toString().padStart(2, "0")`

Comment: @Tomlanthom you don't have any answer, you have a Question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're missing a `return` statement before writign the result on screen.

```js
var timer2 = "0:5";
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  var timer = timer2.split(':');
  var minutes = parseInt(timer[0], 10);
  var seconds = parseInt(timer[1], 10);
  --seconds;
  minutes = (seconds < 0) ? --minutes : minutes;

  if (minutes < 0) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    return;                     /* ADD THIS */
  }

  seconds = (seconds < 0) ? 59 : seconds;
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
  //minutes = (minutes < 10) ?  minutes : minutes;
  $('.countdown').html(minutes + ' minutes : ' + seconds + ' seconds');
  timer2 = minutes + ':' + seconds;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countdown"></div>
```

otherwise (without the `return`) make sure your `seconds` are also at `0`

```js
var timer2 = "0:5";
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  var timer = timer2.split(':');
  var minutes = parseInt(timer[0], 10);
  var seconds = parseInt(timer[1], 10);
  --seconds;
  minutes = (seconds < 0) ? --minutes : minutes;

  if (minutes === 0 && seconds === 0) clearInterval(interval);  /* EDIT */

  seconds = (seconds < 0) ? 59 : seconds;
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
  //minutes = (minutes < 10) ?  minutes : minutes;
  $('.countdown').html(minutes + ' minutes : ' + seconds + ' seconds');
  timer2 = minutes + ':' + seconds;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countdown"></div>
```